# CakePHP reading Cookie with multiple dots

Tags: cookies, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP to develop a website and currently struggling with cookie.
The problem is that when I write cookie with multiple dots,like,

```
$this->Cookie->write("Figure.1.id",$figureId);
$this->Cookie->write("Figure.1.name",$figureName);`
```

and then read, cakePHP doesn't return nested array but it returns,

```
array(
    '1.id' => '82',
    '1.name' => '1'
)
```

I expected something like

```
array(
    (int) 1 => array(
         'id'=>'82',
         'name'=>'1'
    )
)
```

Actually I didn't see the result for the first time when I read after I write them. But from second time, result was like that. Do you know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it doesn't look as if multiple dots are supported. If you look at the read() method of the CookieComponent (http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-CookieComponent.html#256-289), you see this:

```
277:         if (strpos($key, '.') !== false) {
278:             $names = explode('.', $key, 2);
279:             $key = $names[0];
280:         }
```

and that explode() method is being told to explode the name of your cookie into a maximum of two parts around the dot.

You might be best serializing the data you want to store before saving and then deserializing after reading as shown here: http://abakalidis.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/cakephp-storing-multi-dimentional.html

Comment: I thought it would work in the same way as Model dot notation works. Thank you.